# array list of objects with 2-tupel (string, boolean) inside it: program doesn't run

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a solver for my Sokoban game (level 4 of Sokoban for iPhone). The program doesn't run. I don't know exactly why.

At first: Here is the program Lösungsfinder.java (excuse me for my German comments)

```
//variables
//stones s1, ..., s6 with their starting points
//person p with its starting point
//person fiktivePerson with the same starting point as person

//methods
//TestLauf(int iterationen)
//main: Creates Testlauf-instance and starts the method TestLauf with the given number of iterations
//zufallsRichtung(): choses randomly a number out of {0,1,2,3}
//steinDa(int breite, int höhe): Is there a Stein?
//welcherSteinDa(int breite, int höhe): Welcher Stein ist da? (nur anwenden, wenn einer da steht)
//istFrei(int breite, int höhe): Feld und kein Stein drauf?

//Konstruktion mit Positionen Steine, Person, fiktivePerson
//main, die TestLauf-Objekt ausführt & TestLauf(iterationen): letzteres nutzt zufallsRichtung()
//steinDa(breite,höhe)
//welcherSteinDa(breite,höhe)
//istFrei(breite,höhe): kein Stein da?

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lösungsfinder {

    //so, wie es wahrscheinlich anfängt, schon vorher eingefädelt
    Stein s1 = new Stein(0,-2);
    Stein s2 = new Stein(0,-1);
    Stein s3 = new Stein(0,0);
    Stein s4 = new Stein(-1,-1);
    Stein s5 = new Stein(0,2);
    Stein s6 = new Stein(1,2);
    Person p = new Person(1,-2);
    Person fiktivePerson = new Person (1,-2);

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Lösungsfinder lf = new Lösungsfinder();
        lf.TestLauf(1000);
    }

    void TestLauf(int iterationen){
        for (int i=0; i<iterationen; i++){
            schrittGehen();
        }
    }

    //einen Schritt machen: das davor ist einfach
    //ArrayList<Object> alleMöglichkeiten = alleMöglichkeiten();
    void schrittGehen(){ //hier soll ein Schritt gemacht werden

        //hier wird die ArrayList<Object>-Variable alleMöglichkeiten deklariert und auf das Ergebnis von alleMöglichkeiten() gesetzt
        ArrayList<Object> alleMöglichkeiten = alleMöglichkeiten(); 
        //String letzteRichtung = "";
            switch (alleMöglichkeiten.size()){
            case 1: {
                Object[] richtungUndVerschieben =  (Object[]) alleMöglichkeiten.get(0); //einzige Möglichkeit gegeben; diese ist in richtungUndVerschieben
                String richtung = (String) richtungUndVerschieben[0]; //richtung ist somit gegeben. Bewegung hängt davon ab, ob ein Stein mit verschoben werden muss
                boolean mitVerschieben = (boolean) richtungUndVerschieben[1];
                schrittGehenMitAngabe(richtung, mitVerschieben);
            }
            case 2: {
                double x = Math.random();
                int welchenAuswählen = -1;
                if (x<0.5) welchenAuswählen = 0;
                if (0.5 <= x) welchenAuswählen = 1;
                Object[] richtungUndVerschieben =  (Object[]) alleMöglichkeiten.get(welchenAuswählen);
                String richtung = (String) richtungUndVerschieben[0];
                boolean mitVerschieben = (boolean) richtungUndVerschieben[1];
                schrittGehenMitAngabe(richtung, mitVerschieben);
            }
            case 3: {
                double x = Math.random();
                int welchenAuswählen = -1;
                if (x<0.333) welchenAuswählen = 0;
                if (0.333 <= x && x < 0.667) welchenAuswählen = 1;
                else welchenAuswählen = 2;
                Object[] richtungUndVerschieben =  (Object[]) alleMöglichkeiten.get(welchenAuswählen);
                String richtung = (String) richtungUndVerschieben[0];
                boolean mitVerschieben = (boolean) richtungUndVerschieben[1];
                schrittGehenMitAngabe(richtung, mitVerschieben);
            }
            case 4: {
                double x = Math.random();
                int welchenAuswählen = -1;
                if (x<0.25) welchenAuswählen = 0;
                if (0.25 <= x && x < 0.5) welchenAuswählen = 1;
                if (0.5 <= x && x < 0.75) welchenAuswählen = 2;
                if (0.75 <= x) welchenAuswählen = 3;
                Object[] richtungUndVerschieben =  (Object[]) alleMöglichkeiten.get(welchenAuswählen);
                String richtung = (String) richtungUndVerschieben[0];
                boolean mitVerschieben = (boolean) richtungUndVerschieben[1];
                schrittGehenMitAngabe(richtung, mitVerschieben);
            }//case 4
        }//switch
    } //schrittGehen

void schrittGehenMitAngabe(String richtung, boolean mitVerschieben){
    switch(richtung){
    case "rechts": {
        p.breite++;
        System.out.println("Person nach rechts.");
        if (mitVerschieben){
            Stein zuBewegenderStein = welcherSteinDa(p.breite,p.höhe);
            zuBewegenderStein.nachRechtsVerschieben();
            System.out.println("Stein nach rechts.");
        }
    } //case rechts
    case "oben":{
        p.höhe++;
        System.out.println("Person nach oben.");
        if (mitVerschieben){
            Stein zuBewegenderStein = welcherSteinDa(p.breite,p.höhe);
            zuBewegenderStein.nachObenVerschieben();
            System.out.println("Stein nach oben.");
        }
    }//case oben
    case "links":{
        p.breite--;
        System.out.println("Person nach links.");
        if (mitVerschieben){
            Stein zuBewegenderStein = welcherSteinDa(p.breite,p.höhe);
            zuBewegenderStein.nachLinksVerschieben();
            System.out.println("Stein nach links.");
        }
    }//case links
    case "unten":{
        p.höhe--;
        System.out.println("Person nach unten.");
        if (mitVerschieben){
            Stein zuBewegenderStein = welcherSteinDa(p.breite,p.höhe);
            zuBewegenderStein.nachUntenVerschieben();
            System.out.println("Stein nach unten.");
        }
    }//case unten
    }//switch richtung
}//schrittGehenMitAngabe()  

//lieftert ein ArrayList<Object>-Objekt mit allen Möglichkeiten als (Richtung, mitVerschieben)
ArrayList<Object> alleMöglichkeiten(){
    ArrayList<Object> möglicheRichtungen = new ArrayList<Object>(); //möglicheRichtungen enthält am Ende eine Liste mit Tupeln (Richtung, mitVerschieben?)

    //nach rechts möglich?
    fiktivePerson.breite = p.breite+1;
    fiktivePerson.höhe = p.höhe;
    if (Spielbrett.imFeld(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
        if(!steinDa(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "rechts";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = false;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //kein Stein da, also Schrittmöglichkeit
        }
        else{
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "rechts";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = true;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //Stein da, aber rechts davon frei
        } //else-Anweisung von "kein Stein da"
    }//if imFeld

    //nach oben möglich?
    fiktivePerson.breite = p.breite;
    fiktivePerson.höhe = p.höhe+1;
    if (Spielbrett.imFeld(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
        if(!steinDa(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "oben";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = false;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //kein Stein da, also Schrittmöglichkeit
        }
        else{
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "oben";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = true;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //Stein da, aber rechts davon frei
        } //else-Anweisung von "kein Stein da"
    }//if imFeld

    //lach links möglich?
    fiktivePerson.breite = p.breite-1;
    fiktivePerson.höhe = p.höhe;
    if (Spielbrett.imFeld(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
        if(!steinDa(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "links";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = false;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //kein Stein da, also Schrittmöglichkeit
        }
        else{
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "links";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = true;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //Stein da, aber rechts davon frei
        } //else-Anweisung von "kein Stein da"
    }//if imFeld

    //nach unten möglich?
    fiktivePerson.höhe = p.höhe-1;
    fiktivePerson.breite = p.breite;
    if (Spielbrett.imFeld(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
        if(!steinDa(fiktivePerson.breite, fiktivePerson.höhe)){
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "unten";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = false;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //kein Stein da, also Schrittmöglichkeit
        }
        else{
            Object[] richtungMitVerschieben = new Object[2];
            richtungMitVerschieben[0] = "unten";
            richtungMitVerschieben[1] = true;
            möglicheRichtungen.add(richtungMitVerschieben); //Stein da, aber rechts davon frei
        } //else-Anweisung von "kein Stein da"
    }//if imFeld

    return möglicheRichtungen;

    //jetzt sind bei möglicheRichtungen alle möglichen Richtungen zu finden
    //return null;
}

//testet nicht, ob das überhaupt ein Feld ist
boolean steinDa(int breite, int höhe){
    if (s1.breite == breite && s1.höhe == höhe) return true;
    if (s2.breite == breite && s2.höhe == höhe) return true;
    if (s3.breite == breite && s3.höhe == höhe) return true;
    if (s4.breite == breite && s4.höhe == höhe) return true;
    if (s5.breite == breite && s5.höhe == höhe) return true;
    if (s6.breite == breite && s6.höhe == höhe) return true;
    return false;
}

//möglichst nur aufrufen, wenn schon klar ist, dass ein Stein da ist. Sonst gibt er in falschen Situationen s6 zurück
Stein welcherSteinDa(int breite, int höhe){
    if (s1.breite == breite && s1.höhe == höhe) return s1;
    if (s2.breite == breite && s2.höhe == höhe) return s2;
    if (s3.breite == breite && s3.höhe == höhe) return s3;
    if (s4.breite == breite && s4.höhe == höhe) return s4;
    if (s5.breite == breite && s5.höhe == höhe) return s5;
    else return s6;
}

//definieren, ob ein bestimmtes Feld frei ist (d.h. auf dem Spielbrett und nicht durch einen Stein blockiert; durch die Person muss nicht getestet werden)
boolean istFrei (int breite, int höhe){ //darf da ein Stein hingeschoben werden?
    if (Spielbrett.imFeld(breite, höhe)){
        if (!steinDa(breite, höhe)){
            if (!(ecke(breite, höhe))) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

boolean ecke (int breite, int höhe){//ist in einer Ecke drin
    if ((breite == 0 || breite == 1) && höhe == -3) return true; //unten
    if (breite == 2 && (höhe == -2 || höhe == -1)) return true; //rechts
    if (höhe == 3 && (breite == -1 || breite == 1)) return true; //oben
    if (breite == -2) return true; //links
    return false;
}//ecke



}//Lösungsfinder
```

As additional files of the project I have got the file Stein.java:

```
public class Stein {
    int breite;
    int höhe;
    public Stein(int breite, int höhe){
        this.breite = breite;
        this.höhe = höhe;
    }
    void setBreite(int breite){
        this.breite = breite;
    }
    int getBreite(){
        return this.breite;
    }
    void setHöhe(int höhe){
        this.höhe = höhe;
    }
    int getHöhe (int höhe){
        return this.höhe;
    }

    //testet nicht, ob rechts Platz ist
    void nachRechtsVerschieben(){
        this.breite++;
    }
    void nachObenVerschieben(){
        this.höhe++;
    }
    void nachLinksVerschieben(){
        this.breite--;
    }
    void nachUntenVerschieben(){
        this.höhe--;
    }
}
```

and the file Person.java:

```
public class Person {
    int breite;
    int höhe;
    void setBreite(int breite){
        this.breite = breite;
    }
    int getBreite(){
        return this.breite;
    }
    void setHöhe(int höhe){
        this.höhe = höhe;
    }
    int getHöhe(){
        return höhe;
    }
    Person(int breite, int höhe){
        this.breite = breite;
        this.höhe = höhe;
    }
    Person(){
        this.breite = 0;
        this.höhe = 3;
    }
}
```

Here are the errors that I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Lösungsfinder.schrittGehen(Lösungsfinder.java:93)
    at Lösungsfinder.TestLauf(Lösungsfinder.java:47)
    at Lösungsfinder.main(Lösungsfinder.java:42)
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code. I think there is something wrong with my ArrayList-objects which are tuples with the first component as a string and the second component as a boolean. Can anyone help? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you show which lines the error occurs at (93, 47, 42)

Comment: It looks like you're accessing an index which isn't in the ArrayList. It might be easier to debug if you were using specific ArrayList types instead of just ArrayLists of Objects. (I recently switched from iOS, too -- it's different, but it's the "Java way"). In other words, create a TupleWhatever class, and then pass around ArrayList<TupleWhatever>.  That's less fragile than using alternate array indices. You can add additional levels, too: ArrayList<Foo<TupleWhatever>> where Foo is a class which contains instances of TupleWhatevers.  Java "Generics" it's called.  It'll help!

Comment: @MarshallTigerus:
    Line 93: Object[] richtungUndVerschieben =  (Object[])   alleMöglichkeiten.get(welchenAuswählen);
    Line 47: schrittGehen();
    Line 42: lf.TestLauf(1000);

Comment: @MikeBonhoff can you perform a .size() on the array list right before that statement and see how big it is?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: I tested (via .size()) how many numbers where inside alleMöglichkeiten: it were four (like it should have been).